# Обьясните пожалуйста область видимости в Питоне

Tags: python

Итак, у нас есть такая ситуация:

```
from tkinter import *  
x=5  
q=Button()  
def func():  
    x+=2  
    q["text"]="hello"  
func()
```

Здесь у нас произойдет ошибка, так как `x` здесь создается локальная и мы   пытаемся изменить несуществующую переменную.
Мы можем поправить ситуацию:

```
from tkinter import *  
x=5  
q=Button()  
def func():  
    global x  
    x+=2  
    q["text"]="hello"  
func()
```

Здесь ошибок нет, всё прекрасно работает. Мы уточнили, что работаем с   глобальной переменной `х`. Однако с кнопкой `q` мы данную операцию не проводили.   Тогда почему её видно? У меня есть догадка, что объекты видны без применения   global, однако в пайтоне всё является объектами, даже переменные. Как тогда   так получается?

Второй вопрос касается изображения на кнопке.
В данном случае кнопка с картинкой нормально создаются:

```
 def run(root):  
        dialog_window=Tk()  
        img=PhotoImage(file="images//home.gif")  
        Button(root,image=img).place(x=0,y=0)  
        dialog_window.mainloop()  
 run(Tk())
```

Однако, если размещать кнопку на dialog_window:
    Button(root,image=img).place(x=0,y=0)
То ничего не выйдет и интерпретатор выдаст следующее:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):  
      File "D:\projects\Tk_editor\test.py", line 14, in <module>  
        run(Tk())  
      File "D:\projects\Tk_editor\test.py", line 12, in run  
        Button(dialog_window,image=img).place(x=0,y=0)  
      File "C:\Users\Kastiel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 
 32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2209, in __init__  
        Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)  
      File "C:\Users\Kastiel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 
 32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2139, in __init__  
        (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))  
    _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

В чем проблема? И как создать эту кнопку на втором окне?
P.S: Та же кнопка без картинки нормально создается на втором окне:

```
def run(root):
    dialog_window=Tk()
    Button(dialog_window).place(x=0,y=0)
    dialog_window.mainloop()
run(Tk())
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: Не нужно в один вопрос писать несколько вопросов.

Answer (score 2):

По первому вопросу:

Посмотреть значение внешней переменной можно и не указывая специально, что она внешняя. А вот поменять просто так уже нельзя.

По второму вопросу:

Если перемещаете Button, то нужно позаботиться, чтобы там была правильная переменная img, откуда Button тянет картинку. А у вас, похоже, в том месте существует переменная с таким же именем, но неправильным значением.

UPD: Разобрался. В общем, вы просто неправильно используете tkinter. Для создания диалогового окна нужно использовать не второй Tk(), а Toplevel(). Для кнопок после их создания нужно вызывать метод pack().

```
root = Tk()

def run():
    dialog_window = Toplevel(root)
    img = PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
    b = Button(dialog_window, image=img)
    b.pack()
    dialog_window.mainloop()

run()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: По поводу первого вопроса:  
Почему я могу изменять поле кнопки,не говоря о том,что она  
 внешняя?  
    
По поводу второго:  
К сожалению, другой переменной img там нет 100%.   Дело в чем-то другом
  
P.S: я на сайте впервые,как переносить строку в комментариях?

Comment: По первому вопросу: потому что вы не меняете значение переменной. При записи элемента по индексу вы неявно вызываете специальный метод `__setattr__`, который и меняет значение поля. Вызывать методы   объекта из внешней области видимости можно. Даже если они что-то и меняют.

Comment: По второму вопросу: тогда нужно увидеть весь код. По этому кусочку ничего сказать нельзя.

Comment: from tkinter import *
def run(root):  
    dialog_window=Tk()  
    img=PhotoImage(file="images//home.gif")  
    Button(dialog_window,image=img).place(x=0,y=0)
    dialog_window.mainloop()
run(Tk())
Я специально вынес неработающую часть в отдельный файл, он тоже не работает. Это весь его код.
Как делать новую строку в комментах?

Comment: В комментах нет новой строки. Вы можете отредактировать вопрос, дописав код туда.

Comment: Этот код есть в вопросе, он перед ошибкой

Comment: Дописал в мой ответ правильный код.